# Rename tag [kentico-cloud] to [kentico-kontent]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I'd like to ask the moderators to rename the [kentico-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kentico-cloud) tag to [kentico-kontent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kentico-kontent). 
The product has been [renamed as of today](https://kontent.ai/blog/moving-to-caas-with-kentico-kontent).

Comment: This doesn't look to have been completed.

Comment: Indeed, all the questions still appear under the `kentico-cloud` tag. Could anyone please help?

Comment: I raised a flag to get the [status-completed] tag removed, but it was *declined* with a message saying that this was already completed. I'm at a loss to understand what happened.

Comment: What happened here oO, I had renamed it. Did some one else rename it back or did my rename fail? I will try to poke in the mod room.

Comment: FWIW, my rename was logged in the moderator actions, so I am pretty sure the rename went through. I have pinged a staff to check.

Comment: Does anybody know if this will ever go through? What should I do to speed up the process?

Answer (score -3):

I re-tagged the questions manually. Didn't want to wait :(

Comment: This was a bug on SO side. I was trying to figure out why. You could have atleast pinged me in the message above.... :( ...  Anyway, we can't do anything now. :|